# I'm having trouble with the matrix exponential:

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

In one of my classes, I have to prove the following theorem. Given that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and ${\bf x}(t)$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^n$, prove the following:

> If ${\bf x}'(t) = A{\bf x}(t)$, where $x(0) = {\bf x} _0$, then ${\bf x} (t) =  e^{At} {\bf x}_0$.

The first step is for me to prove that the following series converges:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{ t^k A^k}{k!}.$$

I also need to use the Frechet Derivative, linear systems of differential equations, and the relation to the fundamental matrix.

If someone could help me get started, I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbf x_0$ is actually spelled out "$\mathbf x$ naught". The word "not" means something entirely different. Also, you don't need to _prove_ that $e^{At}$ converges, that is a known result.

Comment: I didn't know how to type the subscript.

Comment: Then [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is for you.

Comment: Can you reduce to diagonalizable or diagonal?

Answer (score 1):

For series of vectors the concept of absolute convergence is the same as for numbers.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\|\frac{t^kA^k}{k!}\right\|\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\|tA\|^k}{k!}\le e^{|t|·\|A\|}.
$$

The derivative of $e^{tA}$ can be computed as the derivative of the series and is $Ae^{tA}=e^{tA}A$.

The auxiliary function $y(t)=e^{-tA}x(t)$ for any solution $x$ of the given ODE satisfies
$$
y'(t)=-e^{-At}Ax(t)+e^{-At}x'(t)=e^{-At}(x'(t)-Ax(t))=0.
$$
Thus $y(t)=y(0)=x(0)=x_0$ and thus $x(t)=e^{tA}x_0$.